# Excel VBA - Title lenght can can cause Run Time Error 1004?

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a macro from a sheet where the field length are real big:

Fields names:

- `Chave Nfe` ***no problem***
- `Total Bruto Produtos` ***no problem***
- `ICMS DIFAL RED UF Destino Total (Lei 8315/2015, Art. 7º, IV C.C. Convênio 52/91, Cláusulas 1° e 2°)` ***ERROR***
- `(...)`

My solution was to change the big names...  It works....

Any one know why?

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks and be safe!

### Error Message

*Run Time Error 1004*

*'Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class'*

[image]

### VBA ERROR

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
        PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").PivotFields( _
        "ICMS DIFAL RED UF Destino Total (Lei 8315/2015, Art. 7º, IV C.C. Convênio 52/91, Cláusulas 1° e 2°)" _
        ), _
        "Contagem de ICMS DIFAL RED UF Destino Total (Lei 8315/2015, Art. 7º, IV C.C. Convênio 52/91, Cláusulas 1° e 2°)" _
        , xlCount
```

### Full Script

```
Sub criar_dinamica_anexo_1()

    'Limpar Anexo 2 coluna AA
    Sheets("ANEXO 2").Select
    Range("AA3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("ANEXO 1").Select
    Cells.Select
    
    Sheets.add.name = "DINAMICA_ANEXO_I"
    
    Sheets("ANEXO 1").Select
    Cells.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "ANEXO 1!R1C1:R1048576C124", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination _
        :="DINAMICA_ANEXO_I!R3C1", TableName:="Tabela dinâmica5", DefaultVersion:= _
        6
    Sheets("DINAMICA_ANEXO_I").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").PivotFields("Chave Nfe")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").PivotFields("Chave Nfe"). _
        Orientation = xlHidden
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").PivotFields("Chave Nfe")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
        PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").PivotFields("Total Bruto Produtos"), _
        "Contagem de Total Bruto Produtos", xlCount
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
        PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").PivotFields( _
        "ICMS DIFAL UF Destino Devido (Lei 8315/2015, Art. 7º, IV)"), _
        "Contagem de ICMS DIFAL UF Destino Devido (Lei 8315/2015, Art. 7º, IV)", _
        xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").PivotFields( _
        "Contagem de ICMS DIFAL UF Destino Devido (Lei 8315/2015, Art. 7º, IV)")
        .Caption = _
        "Soma de ICMS DIFAL UF Destino Devido (Lei 8315/2015, Art. 7º, IV)"
        .Function = xlSum
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
        PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").PivotFields( _
        "ICMS DIFAL RED UF Destino Total (Lei 8315/2015, Art. 7º, IV C.C. Convênio 52/91, Cláusulas 1° e 2°)" _
        ), _
        "Contagem de ICMS DIFAL RED UF Destino Total (Lei 8315/2015, Art. 7º, IV C.C. Convênio 52/91, Cláusulas 1° e 2°)" _
        , xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica5").PivotFields( _
        "Contagem de ICMS DIFAL RED UF Destino Total (Lei 8315/2015, Art. 7º, IV C.C. Convênio 52/91, Cláusulas 1° e 2°)" _
        )
        .Caption = _
        "Soma de ICMS DIFAL RED UF Destino Total (Lei 8315/2015, Art. 7º, IV C.C. Convênio 52/91, Cláusulas 1° e 2°)"
        .Function = xlSum
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False


    
End Sub
```

Comment: ?what's the error

Comment: Run Time Error 1004 'Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class'

Comment: @QHarr If you can help me, you will save a very bad day!  Thanks

Comment: That would suggest that the pivot field name is not correct.

Comment: @BigBen i have recorded the macro that creates the PIVOT TABLE is it possible to have this problem?  Any tips?